In which scenario, Boolean variable keep on updating to true value in Spring Batch program
public class GEPX0101JobStep1Reader
    implements ItemReader<List<GEPX0101JobStep1ReaderDto>> {
  /**
   * Logger variable
   */
  private static final Log LOG =
      LogFactory.getLog(GEPX0101JobStep1Reader.class);

  /**
   * Represents the StepExecution object.
   */
  private transient StepExecution stepExecution;

  @Autowired private transient JobExecutionContextUtil context;

  @Autowired private transient CommonUtil commonUtil;

  
  private transient String jobStep1Prefix;

  private transient String branchCode;

  @Autowired private transient GEPX0101CommonService commonService;

 
  private transient boolean readStatus = true;


  public void setStepExecution(final StepExecution stepExecution) {
    this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
  }

  
  @Override
  public List<GEPX0101JobStep1ReaderDto> read() {
    List<GEPX0101JobStep1ReaderDto> readerDTOList = null;
    if (readStatus) {
      readerDTOList = new ArrayList<>();
      LOG.info("readStatus is true, execute reader operations");
      // Create job step1 logger prefix
      jobStep1Prefix = (String) context.getAttribute(
          stepExecution, CommonConstant.STEP_1_PREFIX);
      // Retrieve branch code
      branchCode =
          commonUtil.getInputJobParameter(stepExecution).getBranchCode();
      // Retrieve zone ID from job input.
      final List<CustomEpixModel> bypassMsgList = getEpxInterfaceData();
      LOG.info("Retriving list of BypassMsgs");
      Map<String, List<PrtDataDto>> sysMsgRefMap = null;
      if (CommonValidations.isValidList(bypassMsgList)) {
        LOG.info(" List of BypassMsgs are not NULL");
        final List<String> sysMsgRefList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (final CustomEpixModel mtMessage : bypassMsgList) {
          final String sysMsgRefNo = mtMessage.getMessageRefNo();
          if (CommonValidations.isValidStringArgument(sysMsgRefNo)) {
            LOG.info("sysMsgRefNo is not NULL");
            sysMsgRefList.add(mtMessage.getMessageRefNo());
          }
        }
        final List<PrtDataDto> prtDataList = getPrtData(sysMsgRefList);
        if (CommonValidations.isValidList(prtDataList)) {
          LOG.info(" List of prtData is not NULL");
          sysMsgRefMap = groupSysMsgRefRecord(prtDataList);
        }
      }

      if (CommonValidations.isValidMap(sysMsgRefMap)
          && CommonValidations.isValidList(bypassMsgList)) {
        LOG.info(" sysMsgRefMap and List of bypassMsgList is not NULL");
        for (final CustomEpixModel customEpixModel : bypassMsgList) {
          if (sysMsgRefMap.containsKey(customEpixModel.getMessageRefNo())) {
            final GEPX0101JobStep1ReaderDto jobStep1ReaderDTO =
                new GEPX0101JobStep1ReaderDto();
            LOG.info(" sysMsgRefMap conatins key");
            final List<PrtDataDto> prtData =
                sysMsgRefMap.get(customEpixModel.getMessageRefNo());
            final MdBankBicMstDto sender = getBankBicData(
                prtData.get(CommonConstant.ZERO).getSENDER_BIC());
            final MdBankBicMstDto receiver = getBankBicData(
                prtData.get(CommonConstant.ZERO).getReceiver_Bic());
            jobStep1ReaderDTO.setBypassMsgs(customEpixModel);
            jobStep1ReaderDTO.setPrtDataList(prtData);
            jobStep1ReaderDTO.setSenderBankData(sender);
            jobStep1ReaderDTO.setReceiverBankData(receiver);
            readerDTOList.add(jobStep1ReaderDTO);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    readStatus = false;
    if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
      LOG.debug(new StringBuilder(LoggingConstant.OUTPUT_PARAMTER)
                    .append(CommonConstant.VAL_READER_DTO)
                    .append(readerDTOList));
    }
    return readerDTOList;
  }
}


This code works correctly from last 1 year but 1 day, the readerStatus keep on updating to value as true so again and again if block meet the condition.
And restart of server it started working fine.
I wanted to know why it happened.
